# Precision measurement of liquid level in a tank which is continuously opened and closed

Tags: sensors, distance-measurement

I need to measure the level of the liquid in a tank. The tank is opened and closed frequently. Measurements are made in milliseconds. I tried to measure the level of the liquid by using an ultrasonic sensor, but the measurement was not accurate enough. I need to measure accurate to one milliliter. Measurements are made from the top of the tank. Can anyone suggest some sensor that will accurately measure the liquid level?

Comment: Do want to measure from the top of the tank or bottom of the tank?

Comment: Is the surface of fluid in the tank stable, or does it have a lot of activity (bubbling, flowing, waves, etc.)?

Comment: Ultrasonic sensors will be "confused" by turbulence and the signal from them will fluctuate. How big is the tank? What precision and accuracy do you require? Measuring to the ml in a 100ml tank is one thing, measuring to 100ml in a 100,000 liter tank is another.

Comment: Measure the weight of the tank.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That's where I was leaning towards as well.  It seems like the easiest way to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use one of the following:

1. level glass

   - allows you to read the height of the liquid outside the tank.
   - The width of the tube would have to be large enough for capillary action to be neglectable
   - If there is a lot of movement inside the tank the water level in the tube might oscillate as well.
2. Electronic hydrostatic manometer

   - Attached to the bottom of the tank you could easily read the pressure and calculate the height of the liquid

Comment: Thank you very much your answer, and welcome on the site. I suggest to give a little bit longer answers (at least 2-3 sentences) to get many upvotes.